# How can I convert a float to ratio?

Tags: command-line, numeric-data

I would like to convert a float to a ratio or fraction.

Do we have the option to convert a float `1.778` to ratio as `16:9` or `16/9` in bash, in a fashion similar to Python's [fractions module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html) (`Fraction(1.778).limit_denominator(100)`).

Comment: Unfortunately, `bash` is really bad at floating-point arithmetic; you already wouldn't come from `16/9` to `1.778`. I think an external tool such as `bc` will be needed - but even then, back-calculating a floating-point number to the "originating" fraction is not an easy task!

Comment: Describe how you would proceed mathematically to calculate from `1.778` to `16/9` (keyword greatest common divisor).

Comment: @Cyrus I'm able to do the same with python using `fraction` module... the same I require in bash since I can't use python in my env...

Comment: What precision are you working to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pedantic or not, if our man is looking only looking at 3 decimals of precision....

Breaking out the good old `awk` hammer for the equally good old fashioned **lowest** denominator, rather than the high falutin' algorithm, just find the lowest error and denominator

```
echo "1.778" | awk 'BEGIN{en=1; de=101; er=1}{
    for (d=100; d>=1; d--) {n=int(d*$1); e=n/d-$1; e=e*e;
    if (e<=er && d<de){er=e; de=d; en=n}}
    print en":"de, en/de}'
```

So...

```
16:9 1.77778
```

Something like this could equally be done in pure `bash` with the appropriate multiplier for the fraction.

**If we are having a race**

```
real    0m0.004s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.003s
```

Comment: Indeed you are quite correct. And that is why I asked about precision at the very start... if the question had been to 10 sig figs then I wouldn't have posted this code... but it wasn't.

Answer (score 3):

```
awk -v prec=0.001 -v max=2000 '
   function fract(n, k, kr, d){
       for(k=n;k<max;k+=n){
           kr=int(k+.5); d=kr-k; if(d<0)d=-d;
           if(d<prec){return kr"/"k/n}
       }
       return n" ??"
   }
   BEGIN{for(i=1;i<ARGC;i++)print fract(ARGV[i])}
' 3.1415926535 1.77777777 0.333333 2.71828 1.61803398
355/113
16/9
1/3
1264/465
987/610
```

It could be made more precise by multiplying instead of repeatingly adding, but that could also make it slower:

```
awk -v prec=0.00005 -v max=20000 '
   function fract(n, k, kr, kf, d){
       for(k=1;k<max;k++){
           kf=n*k; kr=int(kf+.5); d=kr-kf; if(d<0)d=-d;
           if(d<prec){return kr"/"k}
       }
       return n" ??"
   }
   BEGIN{for(i=1;i<ARGC;i++)print fract(ARGV[i])}
' 3.14159265358979323846 1.7777777 0.33333333 2.7182818 1.61803398
355/113
16/9
1/3
34109/12548
24476/15127
```

(the `max` "tunable" is actually `max_numerator / orig_num` in this second version).

Answer (score 1):

16 / 9 is not 1.778. It is (to 50 places):

1.77777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777

Conversely, 16.002 / 9 really is exactly 1.778.

So in fact there is no possible number that is exactly 16 / 9 (at least, not in base 10 and with a finite number of digits).

You need to define an acceptable level of accuracy in your approximation.

My first brute-force algorithm would be to try a double loop in A and B, calculate A / B, and stop when it was accurate to (maybe) 6 digits.

The shell script:

```
#! /bin/bash

function Ratio {

AWK='
function Ratio (min, max, Local, a, b, q) {
    for (a = 1; a < 1e6; a++) {
        for (b = 1; b <= a; b++) {
            q = (a / b);
            if (min < q && q < max) {
                printf ("Ratio %d / %d is %.12f\n", a, b, q);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
{ Ratio( $1, $2); }
'   
    awk "${AWK}"
}

    {
        echo 2.8897 2.8899
        echo 1.77777777777 1.77777777778 
        echo 3.14159292 3.14159293
    } | Ratio
```

And here the application:

```
paul $ time ./Ratio
Ratio 341 / 118 is 2.889830508475
Ratio 16 / 9 is 1.777777777778
Ratio 355 / 113 is 3.141592920354

real    0m0.085s
user    0m0.072s
sys     0m0.012s
```

Obviously, if you start with 1.778 (> 1), then there is no point checking any cases where A <= B. That suggests there is a family of approximations based on continuous fractions. So my second algorithm would be to find a general method of constructing an infinite series that converges to a specified value. But only if I had to deal with a serious number of cases.

Comment: The OP clarified that they’re using a denominator limit, looking for the closest approximation with a denominator less than 100.

Comment: And the smallest such denominator, else 96/54 is equally accurate.

Comment: Fractions are typically represented in reduced form, I wouldn’t expect 96/54 instead of 16/9.

Comment: My point is that even if an algorithm produces 96/54, I’d reduce the faction before presenting it.

Comment: OK, so this whole discussion is appropriately pedantic ;-).

Comment: If we take the quantum view, then nothing is exactly equal to anything... at least not for very long....